# alignment is out

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, teradata

I got the below code working to return as string. However, the output returns is a messy code which all alignment is out. is there anyway to return the store procedure as the original coding?

```
command = "SHOW PROCEDURE Inventory.pr_demand_curr()"

using (TdConnection cn = new TdConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            TdCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = command;

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               output += reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        return output;
```

Comment: I wonder if  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure; can solve this problem? I tried to add this below CreateCommand() but the query failed as teh executeReader() failed to read the show store procedure..

Comment: What format is the data in the column? Do you need to add new lines after each GetString() for example?